# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character

Tags: c#-4.0

I am struggling since last 2-3 days in finding out the resolution for below exception:

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character,
more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the
padding characters.
```

I searched for similar questions and found answers but none of them work for me. Here is the data which I am trying to convert:

```
{\"Package\":[{\"Faq\":[{\"FaqId\":1,\"AppId\":65,\"Title\":\"Test1\",
 \"Description\":\"Test1\",\"IsRemoved\":false,\"AddDate\":1344969000,
 \"LastUpdated\":1344969000},{\"FaqId\":2,\"AppId\":65,\"Title\":\"Test2\",
 \"Description\":\"Test2\",\"IsRemoved\":false,\"AddDate\":1344969000,
 \"LastUpdated\":1344969000}]}\r\n]}\r\n"
```

Now I am unable to identify which are the non-base 64 characters. And if there are which are those? and how to remove them?

c# line of code which I am using to parse the string:

```
data.Data = Convert.FromBase64String(data.Data.ToString());
```

`data.Data` contains the above data.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your are trying the wrong way. FromBase64String converts FROM Base64 (i.e. takes a Base64 encoded string and converts it to the original), not TO Base64 (takes a normal string and converts to base64 encoding). Since the string you give the method is not base64-encoded, it bails out.

Answer (score 0):

If "{\"Package\":[{\"Faq\":[{\"FaqId\":1,\"AppId\":65,\"Title\":\"Test1\",\"Description\":\"Test1\",\"IsRemoved\":false,\"AddDate\":1344969000,\"LastUpdated\":1344969000},{\"FaqId\":2,\"AppId\":65,\"Title\":\"Test2\",\"Description\":\"Test2\",\"IsRemoved\":false,\"AddDate\":1344969000,\"LastUpdated\":1344969000}]}\r\n]}\r\n" is the string you are trying to convert, then it is really not a base 64 valid input. You can create a converted version here http://base64converter.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is JSON, not BASE64. Use a JSON deserializer such as [JSON.NET](http://json.net/).

Answer (score 0):

```
data.Data = Convert.FromBase64String(data.Data.ToString());
// NOTE: The packager has some different behavior because it GZIPs the output.
// service cleanup, logging, and outgoing response. NOTE: the ORDER of this is important.
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json";
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=package.json");

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
    man.Save("Package served.");
});

return new MemoryStream((byte[])data.Data);
```

Here is my code. Now if remove base64 conversion and deserialize the json then it fails in saving the json file. It throws an error that json file cannot be saved, unable to read the source.